# Making an iAD delegate

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I want to add

```
- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
```

but it won't let me, I can't figure out what to put HERE, to make it an iAD Delegate:

```
@interface MyAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, HERE>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out I needed to include:

```
 #import <iAd/ADBannerView.h>
```

and use this for HERE:

```
ADBannerViewDelegate
```